# Which is correct - "doesn't made you happy" or "won't made you happy"?

Tags: word-choice, questions, subjunctives, do-support

Which of the following is correct?

> If it doesn't made you happy in the end, is it worth it?
>
> If it won't made you happy in the end, is it worth it?

Is there different meaning?

What I'm trying to say is: think about what you are doing, if you don't feel happy in the end, is it worth doing?

Comment: Both sentences are ungrammatical, I'm afraid. Are they meant to be questions? You have inverted the subject pronoun with its auxiliary  verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your examples are wrong grammatically. You use a past participle where an infinitive is required: "made" should be "make."

There is no doubt English verbs are hard. English forms a lot of verbs with compounds. I like to distinguish between compounds using modal and auxiliary verbs.

Compounds formed with modals like "will" or "may" or "do" always work modal + **infinitive** of the main verb. "Will make" or "do make" for example. Any inflection will occur with respect to the modal. Except for "do," modals have a more limited range of inflection than other verbs.

Compounds formed with auxiliaries always work auxiliary + **participle** of the main verb. The infinitives of the two auxiliaries are "be" and "have."  Any inflection will occur with respect to the auxiliary. (The inflection of both auxiliaries is complete, but irregular. The inflection of "be" is very irregular.) There are two participles. "Have" works only with the past participle and forms perfect tenses. "Be" can work either with the present participle to form progressive tenses or with the past participle to form passive constructions.

And even more complex compounds can be formed involving both a modal and the infinitive of an auxiliary plus a participle or two such as "I shall have been running on the beach for an hour by then." As I said, English verbs are hard.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is grammatical, but both can be made grammatical with small changes.

> If it doesn't **make** you happy in the end, is it worth it?
>
> If it won't **make** you happy in the end, is it worth it?

Both of these mean what you want to express, and I can't think of a better way to phrase the sentiment. (The former feels a little more natural to me, but I think that's a personal preference.)